# Configure openldap CentOS 6.5 PHP --with-ldap failing

Tags: php, openldap, apache2.4, software-collections

I am using and trying to configure the below things:

CentOS 6.5
Apache 2.4
PHP 5.6 --with-ldap

Found an error ldap not found.

```
yum list installed | grep openldap
```

shows openldap installed:

```
openldap.x86_64                     2.4.40-16.el6                       @base
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Why trying to build from sources, when binary packages exists ?

See [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/), initially written for CentOS 7 but suitable for CentOS 6 using the httpd24 collection.

See section 2 about Running a recent PHP version.

The ldap extension is available in the repository.